# Disable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) if user did not accepted cookies

Tags: javascript, html, security, cookies, hsts

I need to activate HSTS on my webserver. But what should I do if the user did not allowed cookies by clicking "no" on my 'do you accept our cookies' alert?

Can I theoretically disable HSTS in such cases or is it always active?
I know It would not make sense, but does it work?

Comment: Why would you disable HSTS if the user didn't accept cookies? What do cookies have to do with HSTS?

Comment: HSTS has nothing to do with cookies, unless you're talking about some people using HSTS as a "super cookie" (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79518/what-are-hsts-super-cookies) which is more of a hack around the way HSTS works than anything your cookie policy should be concerned with IMHO...

Comment: @GaborLengyel, Because of the DSGVO in Europe. HSTS is a "super cookie" according to some websites.

Comment: This is somewhat out of bounds here, but quite frankly, I find that to be bollocks. Even the DSGVO allows you to store *some* stuff, especially if it's a technical necessity.

Comment: @Black My personal opinion is that it makes about zero sense (while I understand it could be misused if you really wanted). HSTS is not a "super cookie", and you should not ever disable it. No regulation prescribes that, and any security best practice tells you to use HSTS.

Comment: Well, our Data Protection Supervisor has to decide this. Maybe I can convince him that it is not a cookie, even though it seems to be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, due to a chicken and egg problem. HSTS is a header sent by the server. The only way the server would know to *omit* that header is if the client sent something in the request that would signal that. There's no "opt-out-of-HSTS" request header, so it would have to be something else stored permanently, like… a cookie. Which obviously defeats the purpose.

Further, the server would not be able to set the HSTS header on any *first visit*. And that rather defeats the purpose of HSTS.